# bad post request, code: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR', errno: 1048, sqlMessage: "Column 'user_name' cannot be null", sqlState: '23000' (angular)

Tags: mysql, angular, express, web

> I have a problem with posting data to Api and sending it to the database, the values are sent NULL to the >database.
> here is the code i used:
> [component typescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ny8c.png)
> [component html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73HYL.png)
> [api node.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qibbz.png)

> I tested the Api on postman and its working good also tried the front end part to make Http Request and >send data to firebase and its working too, but when I connected both of them I get this error.

Comment: What is the full output code of `INSERT INTO user SET ?` .. and please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75807445/edit) and repost those codes as texts.. not as image

Answer (score 0):

On Angular, you are mapping `fname`, but the API are receiving `user_name`.
If the keyword `user_` are being set in front of all params, so you should write as bellow at the Node API:

```
let name = req.body.user_fname;
```